# Adding bower components to vue webpack

Tags: bower, vuejs2, vue.js

Is there any way to add bower_components to vue-webpack.
I tried some way it does not work.

**webpack.base.conf.js** 
http://pastebin.com/Gae193xP 
**Component file**

```
<script type="text/babel">
  import $ from 'jquery'
  require('x-editable')
</script>
```

Error
[image]

Comment: Can you please add the ways you tried and what error you got.

Comment: @Saurabh Quested edited.

Answer (score 1):

You should config the webpack config file for resolving packages from bower. For example, in webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ["web_modules", "node_modules", "bower_components"]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
        new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin(".bower.json", ["main"])
      )
  ]
}
```

You may refer to https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-bower.html

Answer (score 0):

You should load the script file from the place you want to use it. Webpack will load it and include it in your build.js

```
<-- componentX.vue -->
...
<script lang="js">
import jquery from "../bower_components/jquery/jquery.js";

...
</script>
```